# Selecting certain nodes in order of appearance

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to have my code to pick out the first 3 words of a document, if the first wd is a number.

However, for some reason, the second and third nodes aren't being selected properly.
My code shows how I selected the first node, and the two ways I've tried to select the subsequent nodes.

```
       <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       xmlns:ss="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd">
       <xsl:output method="text" /> 
       <xsl:template match="/">           
       <xsl:value-of select="//ss:wd[1]"/>
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>     
          <xsl:value-of select="following::ss:wd"/>
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>     
          <xsl:value-of select="//ss:wd[2]"/>
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:template match="/">
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the "following" axes term returns nothing, and the [2] term returns a wd in line 600 (near the other end of the document).
I can't see how the wd[2] is even slightly related to the position of wd[1].

What am I missing here?

Input XML example:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLT.xsl"?>
<document xmlns="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<page ocr-vers="OmniPageCSDK18" app-vers="OmniPage 19">
<description>
<source file="C:\Users\User\Documents\OCR\Unprocessed\7740412641.pdf" dpix="300" dpiy="300" sizex="2480" sizey="3509"/>
<theoreticalPage size="A4" marginLeft="1440" marginTop="0" marginRight="1440" marginBottom="1440" offsetX="-2" offsetY="-2" width="11918" height="16854"/>
</description>
<body>
<dd l="87" t="322" r="9667" b="16536">
<dd l="115" t="322" r="9667" b="16536">
<picture l="115" t="322" r="9667" b="16536" alignment="left">
</picture>
</dd>
<dd l="7205" t="1027" r="7366" b="1502">
<para l="7234" t="1027" r="7354" b="1502" alignment="left" spaceBefore="29" spaceAfter="4" lsp="exactly" lspExact="120" language="en">
<ln l="7234" t="1027" r="7354" b="1502" baseLine="1303" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="700" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="-23">
<wd l="7234" t="1027" r="7354" b="1502">1,044.47</wd>
</ln>
</para>
</dd>
<dd l="6859" t="1027" r="7020" b="1512">
<para l="6888" t="1027" r="7008" b="1512" alignment="left" spaceBefore="29" spaceAfter="4" lsp="exactly" lspExact="120" language="en">
<ln l="6888" t="1027" r="7008" b="1512" baseLine="1302" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="700" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="-21">
<wd l="6888" t="1027" r="7008" b="1512">5,222.37</wd>
</ln>
</para>
</dd>
<dd l="7502" t="1027" r="7663" b="1512">
<para l="7531" t="1027" r="7651" b="1512" alignment="left" spaceBefore="29" spaceAfter="9" lsp="exactly" lspExact="120" language="en">
<ln l="7531" t="1027" r="7651" b="1512" baseLine="1302" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="700" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="-21">
<wd l="7531" t="1027" r="7651" b="1512">6,266.84</wd>
</ln>
</para>
</dd>
<para>
<ln>
<wd>example that's much later</wd>
</ln>
</para>
</dd>
</body>
</page>
</document>
```

Comment: For starters, your question is missing **1** a sample XML input and **2** the entire template, if not the entire stylesheet.

Comment: I didn't think this was necessary, but I'll add it in one moment

Comment: Please always include those things if your question is about XSLT. In most cases, you are asked to add it anyway ;-).

Comment: Ok, will do in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selects the `ss:wd` elements you had in mind. The first line:

```
<xsl:variable name="wds" select="//ss:wd"/>
```

stores all `ss:wd` elements in a variable, so that they are available regardless of where you are in the tree. Then, the template selects the first three elements of the variable.

**Full stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ss="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd">

 <xsl:output method="text" /> 

 <xsl:variable name="wds" select="//ss:wd"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="$wds[1]"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$wds[2]"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
  <xsl:value-of select="$wds[3]"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template> 


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
1,044.47
5,222.37
6,266.84
```

**EDIT: Why your approach does not work**

First of all, the closing tag of your template is:

```
</xsl:template match="/">
```

whereas it should really be:

```
</xsl:template>
```

But that's just a typo maybe. The real issue with your template is your *position* in the tree. In the first place, your position in the tree depends on what element your template matches.

Your templates matches the document node (`/`), so that's your position in the tree. Now, if you apply Xpath expressions with *axes*, those **axes are resolved relative to your position**.

What you really meant to do is:

```
<xsl:template match="ss:wd[not(preceding::ss:wd)]">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:value-of select="following::ss:wd[1]"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="following::ss:wd[2]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The above statement is evaluated from a `wd` element. By the way, this uses another axis, `preceding::`, to make sure you are matching the very first `wd` element.

Comment: Thank you, this does work. Though I am confused as to why my version doesn't. In my mind, this is just a more verbose version of mine.

Comment: Just a second, I'll add an explanation.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expect it to be due to the templates!